# Do I need to alter my reflow profile for a PCB with thicker copper?

Tags: soldering, pcb-assembly, reflow

I have always been working with pretty standard 1 oz. copper PCBs and using a Controleo3 reflow oven with great success. However I am now working on boards that will potentially have 3oz or 4oz copper - will I need to change the reflow profile for these boards (longer soak and reflow time ?) since it will take them longer to heat up since more copper = more thermal mass ?

The solder paste I have always been using is TS391SNL50 from CHIPQUIK.

Comment: My understanding is yes. Although, the assembly house house never seems to ask me what the weight of the copper on my PCBs are.

Comment: Interesting. When we do outsource boards, they usually ask for it in the board details.

Comment: My expectation would be that the thermal mass of the copper is negligible, and the soak time is mainly defined by the thermal conductivity (or lack thereof) of the substrate material. For two-layer boards (as boards with thick copper usually are) I'd also expect it to matter a lot less overall because they are somewhat evenly heated, while a board with inner layers would have thermal gradients around the vias.